# Cannot find C++/CX pplawait.h and await

Tags: visual-studio-2013, c++-cx

I just started looking into C++/CX as a possible more updated route to create a wrapper for C++ native libraries. One thing I found out was a lot of the WinRT API are asynchronous. I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/20/asynchronous-programming-in-c-using-resumable-functions-and-await.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/20/asynchronous-programming-in-c-using-resumable-functions-and-await.aspx) blogs that mention being able to use await in C++/CX but when I try it in my Windows Runtime Component component that I created it says that it cannot find the "pplawait.h" header that it is supposed to be in.

The blogs that I mentioned say that it is available in the Visual Studio 2013 CTP. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 so I'm assuming that it is already in there. Can anyone help me figure out why it's not working for me? Thank you.

Comment: It is not supposed to work, the feature didn't make it into the RTM version.  It is still experimental for the [VS2015 Preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/12/resumable-functions-in-c.aspx).  Treat this as future music.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I couldn't find anything saying that it still not available. I just wanted to make sure that it wasn't because I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions to install the experimental toolset as mentioned in the blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/20/asynchronous-programming-in-c-using-resumable-functions-and-await.aspx